# How to add a custom field under shipping method in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to add a custom input select  field under shipping method in checkout page in magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

> In checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                     
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/customjs</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

then in vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/view/customjs.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko',
'uiComponent'], function ($, ko, Component) {
'use strict';
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Vendor_Module/customtemp'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
      
        return this;
    },
});});
```

and in vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/customtemp.html

```
<div class="step-title" data-role="title" data-bind="i18n: 'Custom Field'">Custom Field</div><div class="control">
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="picker: true" name="custom_data_field" readonly="false"
/></div> <!-- ko --><span class="custom_field" data-bind="text: custom_field" /><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: i will check and update you

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran This is not working